# Sharepoint 2010 moving site collection to different database error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint

I am trying to move a site collection from one content database to another content database.  First I used the following PowerShell command:

```
New-SPContentDatabase -Name New_DB -WebApplication http://portal/
```

I confirmed that this did in fact create the DB in the SQL Server.

I then used the following command:

```
Move-SPSite http://portal/sites/hr -DestinationDatabase New_DB
```

This generates an error stating that the "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Can anyone help point me in the right direction with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Try disabling all the Sharepoint services before moving the database](http://blogs.technet.com/b/balasm/archive/2012/05/18/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object.aspx).